# Which code design pattern should I use in nodejs? How to design good data base?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

I have experience in games development(C/C++/C#) but recently I started writing automated test and I wanted to learn some backend stuff. I'm writin platform for automated backups, making builds from git repo and testing. I decide to write server in Node.js with PostgreSQL. I have 0 experience in web development. Never ever have I use a database or javascript. I think homemade project like that will be a good starting point. I want to ask two questions. First: Which code design patter will be the best for learning Node.js? Second - Could you please tell me if this pre-alpha database concept is currently good or should I change it?[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRkNa.png)

Comment: There is no way for anyone to determine if that database concept is good. Needs to be 10 x more detailed to even begin to analyze it. Also need knowledge of how the infrastructure the DB is for is organized. This leaves a lot of "maybes" and "could work but might not" in the air

Comment: So if this is my first try should I just read the internet about good design - try to make it and if i fail - analyze what went wrong and don't make that mistake when creating another project? I probably just answer my own question :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one will be able to answer your questions as you asked them but I'll try to give you few hints. First of all PostgreSQL is a very good relational database so if you need a relational database then it's a good choice but there are other types of databases like graph databases, document databases, key-value stores etc. that you should also consider when designing your architecture. For anything complex it is common to use more than one database.

It's hard to recommend any code design pattern. I can only recommend starting from a good style guide like the one from Airbnb and enforcing it with a linter - see: http://airbnb.io/javascript/ - and following a style guide writing your backend in a style supported and recommended by a given framework that you're going to use. Some examples: Express, Hapi, Restify, LoopBack, Serverless, Seneca, Koa, Sails, etc. Google all of them and read examples to see which one feels best suited for your needs.

Links to more frameworks to consider:

- http://nodeframework.com/
- https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-nodejs

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will not have any "big" data files in my database. All tests results are in xml and will be stored on cloud. Database will only have a link to it. That is why I didn't choose MongoDB - because if I understand correctly this type of database is not suited in my case. Probably in few months I will be writing my new game and let players save their progress on my server - will it be good to use MongoDB in this case? Save files can be pretty big and if players make a lot of saves database can grow big really really fast.